# Youtube API: Play video in Standard Resolution (NO HD)

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using the Youtube Android Api. Is there a way to force the Youtube player to play the video with HD turned off?

Seems that the method `setPlaybackQuality` is not present on the `YoutubePlayer` class :(

However the player UI does have an "HD" button that toggles HD so the funcionality is obviously there.

Comment: Please provide your answer, If you got solution. I too getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In iframe by doing as below you can specify the video resolution by appending following parameter to URL. Try it if works for android.

```
240p: &vq=small
360p: &vq=medium 
480p: &vq=large 
720p: &vq=hd720
```

For instance:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SK0cUNMnMM
```

becomes:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SK0cUNMnMM&amp;vq=large"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am using the Android Native Api, it doesn't work with URL's, so unfortunately these parameters are not available :(